# I have a widget that takes a long time to build and can't figure out how to show a loading spinner while it loads

Tags: flutter

Update 3: ok finally figured out that even if I get everything to build into a list of widgets async, when I go to display the widgets it hangs up. You’d think that listview would work since it should only load the items in view, but even that hangs and is slow to scroll.

Update 2: I deleted lines until I found that the single line that causes the delay (i.e. isn't run asyncronously no matter what I try) is this: `criteriaRow.add(Row(...))`. I've scoured the internet but it doesn't seem that adding things to a list can be done asyncronously. I must be doing something wrong...

I know how to run async functions and I can see how to use a FutureBuilder, but those are for when the data gathering itself is slow. In this case, I can build the lists and data I need very quickly. But, when I go to create the actual final widget, it takes around 4-5 seconds and hangs up the main thread. How can I build a widget asynchronously?

The clear problem is the `for` loops I have in the widget (see below). When I delete them, it loads quickly.

```
Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Flexible(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Card(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        
                        for(var i in displayRequired1) i,
                        for(var i in displayRequired2) i,

                      ],
                    ),
                  )
              ),
            )
        ),

      ],
    );
```

UPDATE: more complete code (the complete code is way too long to add).

Function that initiates list generation:

```
Future<String> solveCase() async {

  display = displayType.summary;

  // Parse studies early so data is available
  List<ParseTest> ncsResult = [];
  
  // Build required NCS
  displayRequiredNCS.add(
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          width: 200,
          child: Text(
            'Nerve Studies',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: largeFontSize,
                color: colorTextDefault,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            child: Text(
              '',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: largeFontSize,
                  color: colorTextDefault,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
  print('NCS length: ${ncsResult.length}');
  ncsResult.forEach((r) {
    List<Widget> criteriaRow = [];
    if(r.prettyCriteria[0] == '-' || r.prettyCriteria[0] == '+'){
      r.prettyCriteria.split('\n').forEach((e) {
        criteriaRow.add(Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: Text(
                  '${e.substring(1)}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: mediumFontSize,
                      color: colorTextDefault,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              width: 200,
              child: e[0] == '+' ? Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.green) : Icon(Icons.cancel, color: Colors.red),
            ),

          ],
        ),);
      });
    } 

    displayRequiredNCS.add(
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            width: 200,
            child: Text(
              '    ${r.diagnosis}',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: mediumFontSize,
                  color: colorTextDefault,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: criteriaRow,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

  });

  

  print('final');
  return 'test';

}
```

Comment: Can't you use `ListView.builder` for your requirement, I think it is possible to use the same if `Card` and `Container` inside `SingleChildScrollView` is not usefull.

Comment: @AlexSunderSingh I don't think I can. The overall structure is what I need for the page. Even if I break the structure to try a ListView with a constrained height, it still lags 4-5 seconds trying to build the list. I think that FutureBuilder may be the right answer, but I still can't figure out how to implement it so that it waits for all items to be added to the list.

Comment: I added answer, please check out. That may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the both lists `displayRequired1` and `displayRequired2`, then use `ListView.builder`, `ListView` builds when required.

```
  final combinedDisplayRequired = [...displayRequired1, ...displayRequired2];
  Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Flexible(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: combinedDisplayRequired.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => combinedDisplayRequired[index],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
```

Comment: That does eventually display the correct content, but it still has a 5 second delay where the program is frozen. Can't scroll, and any loading wheel I put in view doesn't spin. Somehow the main thread is still doing stuff.

Comment: Can you add full code, so that I can analyse why this happens

Comment: OK I added the 3 functions I think are relevant. I've been trying to make all 3 async so all of the Future and async are edits I've made recently. Basically it parses a string with PetitParser, which takes a long time if the string is complex. It sends the result back to the first function, which is what hangs up.

Comment: Narrowed it down even further to the list of Widgets just taking forever to render. Didn't matter how I async build the list. Even when it was fully ready but just needed to be displayed, there was a delay. That is why even the ListView didn't work, though it was a good idea. I could get it to load faster with ListView, but then scrolling within the view was super slow. Overall it was better in release mode but still 1-2 seconds. It's only an issue when I try and load hundreds of widgets into the UI.

Comment: Ok I haven’t gotten it working yet but it’s now clear to me that you’re right. I think the issue I had with listview is that I still tried to make it display the entire list instead of limiting the height to just display a few rows at a time. This unfortunately will create a double scroll, but it’s the best way. Thanks.